# How to write customised show function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, enums

I am defining a Octave type:

```
data Octave = 1 | 2 | 3
  deriving (Show, Read, Ord, Enum)
```

Since '1' is not valid for data constructor identifiers, I have to do it like so:

```
data Octave = O1 | O2 | O3
  deriving (Show, Eq, Read, Ord, Enum)
```

Now, if I `show Octave O1` it shows "O1" which is not exactly what I want. I want the result to be "1". I know we can customise our Show behaviour like this:

```
instance Show Blabla where                                                                                       
  show (Blabla ints chars list num) =                                                                            
    "integers = " ++ show ints ++ "\n"
```

But the problem is that I am using enumeration type which means it doesn't have a value except its identifier name 'O1'. How can I access that in Haskell?

Another question: How can I read it back?

`read "O1" :: Octave` works, but I want `read "1" :: Octave`

```
instance Read Octave where
  read "1" = O1
  read "2" = O2
  read "3" = O3
```

This doesn't work: "`read` is not a (visible) method of class `Read`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use existing instances for Int, like so:

```
data Octave = O1 | O2 | O3 deriving (Enum,Bounded)

instance Show Octave where
   show = show . (+1) . fromEnum

instance Read Octave where
   readsPrec pr = map (\ (int,str) -> ((toEnum (int-1)),str) . readsPrec pr
```

This correctly renders O1..O3 as 1..3 and reads them back. The only pitfall is when trying to read a different integer, like 4:

```
*** Exception: toEnum{Octave}: tag (3) is outside of enumerations'range (0,2)
```

This could be fixed by writing more code and checking for valid values in readsPred.

Answer (score 6):

Taking advantage of Octave's `Enum` instance and using the `Show` and `Read` instances for `Int` we can implement showing and reading like this:

```
data Octave = O1 | O2 | O3 deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum)

instance Show Octave where
    show o = show (fromEnum o + 1)

instance Read Octave where
    readsPrec prec = map (\(n,s) -> (toEnum (n - 1), s)) . readsPrec prec
```

I.e. `fromEnum` and `toEnum` convert between octaves and ints so that `O1` <-> `0` and `O2` <-> `1`, so we have to adjust by one in both reading and writing.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like all you need is this, right?

```
instance Show Octave where
  show O1 = "1"
  show O2 = "2"
  show O3 = "3"
```

Define `show` with three clauses, and let the pattern matcher figure it out.

Comment: Better than "functions perfectly, trivially easy to write"?

Comment: What if Octave has 8 values?

Comment: If there are eight values of Octave, you'll have to pattern-match all eight of them every time you care about its value, because you've made them into an enum with no other information attached. If this bothers you, you probably shouldn't be defining it as an enum.

Comment: No reflection in Haskell? Another question: How can I read it back? I have updated my question.

Comment: As you can see here [1], the method you have to implement is `readsPrec`, not `read`. The only difference is that `readsPrec` takes an additional `Int`-value as its argument, which describes the operator precedence.

[1] http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t:Read]

Comment: @luckykevin: there are many variants of reflection in Haskell (template haskell is one of them), but for such simple code it's considered over the head.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a different approach:

```
data Octave_ = O1 | O2 | O3 deriving (Show, Eq, Read, Ord, Enum)
newtype Octave = O { unO :: Octave_ }  deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum)

instance Show Octave where
    show = tail . show . unO
```

Depending on what you are doing this could be good or bad.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to access the identifier name. you could use something like [template haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell) to do it but this is a terrible idea.

Actually, the fist bad idea is probably to rely on `show`. `Show` class is traditionally use to "serialize" data, while `Read` class will de-serialize them. If you want to pretty print the output, you'd better write your own `Octave -> String` function. To do so, you *could* rely on the result of `show` (and truncate the result). However, the most efficient solution might be to encode it directly, as proposed by [amalloy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18606920/1730).

Comment: Thx, how about reading it back. I am really bothered by this. I am told to implement a function which must follow the function declaration. And it passes me Strings!!!

Comment: The fact the GHCi uses `show` to display results is a good enough reason to make ADTs instance of `Show` even if there is no way to serialize/deserialize them, IMHO.

Comment: It's also quite easy to add a "prettyPrint ." in front of your ghc line (or to do "prettyPrint it" afterwards).